# Unfortunately Reminderer has Stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi i am making an app in which I am allowing user to add a reminder, but while i do click on *Add New* button getting Error - Unfortunately Reminderer has Stopped.

**AddTaskActivity.java Code:**

```
  public class AddTaskActivity extends Activity {
Task mTask;
Handler mHandler = new AddHandler();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.add_task);

Button add = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.submit);
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    GrammarParser parser = new GrammarParser();
    parser.setAndroidContext(AddTaskActivity.this);
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_task);
    String input = text.getText().toString();
    mTask = parser.parse(input);
    String output = mTask.toString();
    TextView log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log_cat);
    log.setText(output);
    }

});

Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (mTask != null)
        DatabaseInterface.addTask(AddTaskActivity.this, mHandler,
            mTask);

    }

});

Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    finish();

    }

});

}
```

add_task.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/add_new_task" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/log_cat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/no_task"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/cancel" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>

<string name="hello">Hello World, RemindererActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">Reminderer</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world</string>
<string name="add_new_task">Add new</string>
<string name="submit">Submit</string>
<string name="no_task">Sample tasks:\n
    buy eggs\n
    buy eggs 8pm\n
    buy eggs Monday 9am\n
    buy eggs July 1\n
    buy eggs next Monday\n
    buy eggs 8pm repeats daily</string>
<string name="due_now">These task(s) are due now:</string>
<string name="dismiss">Dismiss</string>
<string name="snooze">Snooze</string>
<string name="save">Save</string>
<string name="cancel">Cancel</string>
```

**Logcat Says**:

```
    01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.frankandrobot.reminderer.AddTaskActivity$1.onClick(AddTaskActivity.java:39)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-11 16:05:01.252: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have a NullPointerException on line 39 of AddTaskActivity.java. Could you tell which line in your example code that is?

Comment: Can you post your layout file `add_task`?

Comment: @Grishu I have posted add_task.xml

Comment: @Liza you guess? Just check your file and find line 39... If it *is* that line, you need to check if `parser.parse()` returns `null`, if so you should not use `mTask`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell which line in `onClick()` is causing the *NPE*, as you haven't provided line numbers.  You need to perform more error checking in your code, and use `assert()` more often:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    GrammarParser parser = new GrammarParser();
    parser.setAndroidContext(AddTaskActivity.this);

    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_task);
    assert(text != null);
    String input = text.getText().toString();
    mTask = parser.parse(input);
    if (mTask != null) {
        String output = mTask.toString();
        TextView log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.log_cat);
        assert(log != null);
        log.setText(output);
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse text");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Liza You'll need to post `Parser.Task.toString()` but it seems you are turning into a help vampire.  If my answer helped solved your original problem then using a similar approach may solve this new problem. Either way, we are not going to spend eternity updating this question and my answer to suite.